# keyword events of solve_ivp

Tags: python, integration, numerical-methods, ode, numerical-integration

In my case on hand, fsolve(...) is called on every step of the numerical integration with solve_ivp.
I use a counter to count the times fsolve did not find a solution.
If the counter exceeds a value, I call it cut_off, the integration should stop and the results achieved so far given.

Following Mathew Flamm's advice, given around 9.th June, I defined a function

```
def cutoff_event(..., counter, cutoff):
   if cut_off - counter >= 0:

      return -1.

   else:

      return 1.
```

Doing this I got this error:

```
ValueError: f(a) and f(b) must have different signs
```

Where is my mistake?
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You seem to have a DAE system, you should use a DAE solver. // As previously remarked, an event is a point on the solution curve that is determined as the root of a function that only depends on the coordinates of the point. Your counter does something useful, but is not an event in that sense. // The error message is from the root finder. It expects a sign change in the given interval, but your counter and thus the return of the event function are constant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply!!  I do not think, it is a DAE system, at least the generalized coordinates are not restricted (I try to simulate an ellipse falling on an uneven street. I have to numerically calculate the point where it may hit the street at any step of the iteration, and fsolve does not always converge). This function f(...) which causes the error, as f(a), f(b) do not have different signs, is this the event function, I mean the function where I put events=f ? Thanks again!

Comment: Your event function could be the signed distance to the street, positive when no intersection, negative when intersecting. At that point you need to calculate the interaction anyway, so terminating and restarting with the new state is natural.

Comment: Thanks!! Let me think about this.  As I understand fsolve, there is no way to tell it to stop and give the results achieved thus far if some variable goes from, say, True to False. Thanks again!